# Creating self-contained python applications

Tags: python, windows, executable, self-contained

I'm trying to create a self-contained version of [pisa](http://www.htmltopdf.org/) (html to pdf converter, [latest version](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pisa/3.0.27)), but I can't succeed due to several errors. I've tried `py2exe`, `bb-freeze` and `cxfreeze`.

This has to be in windows, which makes my life a bit harder. I remember that a couple of months ago the author had a zip file containing the install, but now it's gone, leaving me only with the python dependent way.

How would you work this out?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check out [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), it makes standalone executables (as in one .EXE file, and that's it).