# Execute python program without having specific packages in system

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make an EXE file from a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program)

I am looking for a method in which i can run python program without having packages installed in the system.
Is there any way by which we can directly run any python code as an *exe.
or Should I make a executable file which has all packages in it.

The main reason behind this is, able to run python program on system which is not having python/packages in it.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&spell=1&q=convert+Python+script+to+EXE&sa=X&ei=j_33UJCFBsfKrQHsooH4Bw&ved=0CC0QvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41018144,d.aWM&fp=5ba22b36fdca884f&biw=1234&bih=594) has your answer.

Comment: Here's an old post on this topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203487/creating-self-contained-python-applications

Answer (score 1):

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) is what you want. This will build an executable from your source.

The downside is: it packs an interpreter with the exe, so the filesize might become bigger. And when you use external libraries, especially C-bindings, you'll have to make manual steps.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pyinstaller.org/ is another good option. Does a lot of the same things py2exe does and suffers from the same problems.

Comment: Having used both pyinstaller and py2exe I have to say that pyinstaller makes it slightly easier to produce a single exe.